# How to convert voice.csv data into audio wav form?

Tags: python, scipy

I am using voice.csv data to convert it into audio wav form but it has 21 columns and in my code it is expecting only two values(columns), so what changes should I have to make in my code to create a wav form.

The data comes from https://www.kaggle.com/primaryobjects/voicegender which also has a description of the data:

> The following acoustic properties of each voice are measured and included within the CSV:
>
> - meanfreq: mean frequency (in kHz)
> - sd: standard deviation of frequency
> - median: median frequency (in kHz)
> - Q25: first quantile (in kHz)
> - Q75: third quantile (in kHz)
> - IQR: interquantile range (in kHz)
> - skew: skewness (see note in specprop description)
> - kurt: kurtosis (see note in specprop description)
> - sp.ent: spectral entropy
> - sfm: spectral flatness
> - mode: mode frequency
> - centroid: frequency centroid (see specprop)
> - peakf: peak frequency (frequency with highest energy)
> - meanfun: average of fundamental frequency measured across acoustic signal
> - minfun: minimum fundamental frequency measured across acoustic signal
> - maxfun: maximum fundamental frequency measured across acoustic signal
> - meandom: average of dominant frequency measured across acoustic signal
> - mindom: minimum of dominant frequency measured across acoustic signal
> - maxdom: maximum of dominant frequency measured across acoustic signal
> - dfrange: range of dominant frequency measured across acoustic signal
> - modindx: modulation index. Calculated as the accumulated absolute difference between adjacent measurements of fundamental frequencies divided by the frequency range
> - label: male or female

My code expects input in two columns. I was trying to convert these columns into time and frequency and I have tried it by skipping multiple columns but I am not getting the results which I want.

```
import wave
import struct
import sys
import csv
import numpy 
from scipy.io import wavfile
from scipy.signal import resample


def write_wav(data, filename, framerate, amplitude):
wavfile = wave.open(filename,'w')
nchannels = 1
sampwidth = 2
framerate = framerate
nframes = len(data)
comptype = "NONE"
compname = "not compressed"
wavfile.setparams((nchannels,
                    sampwidth,
                    framerate,
                    nframes,
                    comptype,
                    compname))
frames = []
for s in data:
    mul = int(s * amplitude)
    frames.append(struct.pack('h', mul))

frames = ''.join(frames)
wavfile.writeframes(frames)
wavfile.close()
print("%s written" %(filename))


if __name__ == "__main__":
if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
    print ("You must supply a filename to generate")
    exit(-1)
for fname in sys.argv[1:]:

    data = []
    for time, value in csv.reader(open('voice.csv'), delimiter=','):
        try:
            data.append(float(value))#Here you can see that the time column is skipped
        except ValueError:
            pass # Just skip it


    arr = numpy.array(data)#Just organize all your samples into an array
    # Normalize data
    arr /= numpy.max(numpy.abs(data)) #Divide all your samples by the max sample value
    filename_head, extension = fname.rsplit(',',1)        
    data_resampled = resample( arr, len(data) )
    wavfile.write('rec.wav', 16000, data_resampled) #resampling at 16khz
    print ("File written succesfully !")






ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-10-ad8c56a24b4d> in <module>
  6 
  7         data = []
----> 8         for time, value in csv.reader(open('voice.csv'), 
delimiter=','):
  9             try:
 10                 data.append(float(value))#Here you can see that the 
time column is skipped

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Without knowing anything about the data you're working with, one of the problems is that `for time, value in csv.reade(...)` is not how you read a csv line by line. Take a look at the csv module [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) for a basic example. Your code also attempts to loop over command line arguments but then opens and writes to the same files every time.

Answer (score 2):

The file contains statistical aggregates, not actual audio data. There is no way you could reverse engineer a faithful audio signal from just these overall measurements.

In so many words, this is like trying to create a terrain profile between two points from just the distance and the time travelled. Additional measurement data like difference in altitude or average acceleration over the time period will *drastically* constrain the number of possible guesses, but you're still guessing, wildly.

Comment: So, Is there any way that I could reshape this data into two columns?

Comment: I'm sure there is, but you are totally missing the point. Your code expects samples and there is no way to turn the data you have into samples.

Comment: You can turn 20 km/h into a series of data points like 1 km every 3 minutes (or throw in randomization to make it look more realistic) but this has very little chance of representing the actual performance which resulted in the measurement 20 km/h.